# R: Recursive *ply/plyr function; for loop replacement

Tags: r, recursion, plyr, apply

I am trying to replace a for loop with a *ply type function.

The issue I am having is that I'm not sure how to update the same data repetitively.

Here is some sample data (I know this specific example could be done other ways but this is just for simplicity -- my real example is much more complicated):

```
sample_pat_rep <-  data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Pattern","Replacement"))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
sample_pat_rep[1,] <-  c("a","A")
sample_pat_rep[2,] <-  c("b","B")
sample_pat_rep[3,] <-  c("c","C")

sample_strings <-  data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Original","Fixed"))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
sample_strings[1,] <-  c("aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc","aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc")
sample_strings[2,] <-  c("aAaAaAaA bBbBbBbB cCcCcCcC","aAaAaAaA bBbBbBbB cCcCcCcC")
sample_strings[3,] <-  c("AaAaAaAa BbBbBbBb CcCcCcCc","AaAaAaAa BbBbBbBb CcCcCcCc")
```

Here is a for loop version:

```
sample_strings1 <- sample_strings
for (i in 1:nrow(sample_pat_rep))
{
  sample_strings1[,c("Fixed")] <- gsub(sample_pat_rep[i,c("Pattern")], sample_pat_rep[i,c("Replacement")], sample_strings1[,c("Fixed")],ignore.case = TRUE)
}
```

When I try to replicate this with adply, it will not update the data -- it essential replicates and rbinds it.

```
sample_strings2 <- adply(.data=sample_pat_rep, .margins=1, .fun = function(x,data){

data[,c("Fixed")] <- gsub(x[,c("Pattern")], x[,c("Replacement")], data[,c("Fixed")],ignore.case = TRUE)
return(data)

}, data=sample_strings, .expand = FALSE, .progress = "none", .inform = FALSE, .parallel = FALSE, .paropts = NULL)
```

I'm sure there is an easy fix. I looked at Rapply but it wasn't clear that this was the fix.

Maybe write a function that makes the call?? Use Rapply??

Thanks ahead of time!

---

UPDATE:  NEW DATA

This is closer to an actual scenario.  The matches are dynamic and based off a external system.  I am trying to avoid overly-complicated regex or nested if elses.

```
library(plyr)

sample_match <-  data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=1, nrow=3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Match"))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
sample_match[1,] <-  c("dog")
sample_match[2,] <-  c("cat")
sample_match[3,] <-  c("bear")

sample_strings <-  data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=2, nrow=3, dimnames=list(c(), c("Sentence","Has_Animal"))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
sample_strings[1,] <-  c("This person only has a cat",0)
sample_strings[2,] <-  c("This person has a cat and a dog",0)
sample_strings[3,] <-  c("This person has no animals",0)

sample_strings1 <- sample_strings
for (i in 1:nrow(sample_match))
{
 sample_strings1[,c("Has_Animal")] <- ifelse(grepl(sample_match[i,c("Match")], sample_strings1[,c("Sentence")]), 1,sample_strings1[,c("Has_Animal")])
} 


sample_strings2 <- adply(.data=sample_match, .margins=1, .fun = function(x,data){

 data[,c("Has_Animal")] <- ifelse(grepl(x[,c("Match")], data[,c("Sentence")]), 1,data[,c("Has_Animal")])
 return(data)

}, data=sample_strings, .expand = FALSE, .progress = "none", .inform = FALSE, .parallel = FALSE, .paropts = NULL)
```

Comment: can't resist asking: you can't use `toupper()`?

Comment: I could for this example but my real case doesn't have anything to do with gsub.  This was just the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: It isn't related to gsub, either? hm.  could you give us an example of the *actual* problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a straight `plyr` approach to the question:

```
ddply(sample_strings,.(Sentence),function(x,ref = sample_match) {
  any(unlist(strsplit(x[["Sentence"]]," ")) %in% ref[[1]])
  })

                         Sentence    V1
1 This person has a cat and a dog  TRUE
2      This person has no animals FALSE
3      This person only has a cat  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Misunderstood the question, that `sample_strings2` was the required result. Updated the answer that gives `sample_strings1` now, which IIUC is what's required.

Here's a solution using `base`:

```
pattern = paste(sample_match$Match, collapse="|")
transform(sample_strings, Has_Animal = grepl(pattern, Sentence)*1L)

#                          Sentence Has_Animal
# 1      This person only has a cat          1
# 2 This person has a cat and a dog          1
# 3      This person has no animals          0
```

---

If you don't want to match words that contain the pattern within, for ex: `concatenate` contains `cat`, then you can use the regex `\b` for word boundary.

```
pattern = paste(paste("\\b", sample_match$Match, "\\b", sep=""), collapse="|")
grepl(pattern, c("cat", "concatenate"))
# [1] TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Arun, I appreciate this but this does the same thing as my adply function.  I am looking for a final dataset that is 3 rows, those three are getting updated instead of three rows everytime being appended.  For instance, the for loop answer has 3 rows.